# How does get method call in routes.rb actually create named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails routes.rb file, say I have added the code

```
get "/articles" => "A#B", as: "arts"
```

Then by simply including the code

```
as: "arts"
```

how, and in which file does the "arts_path" method get created?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the "how". This is called "metaprogramming". Code that writes code. Here is a super-simplified example of how this could be implemented.

`get` is a method which simply calls `define_method` (directly or via a few levels of indirection).

```
module Routable
  def get(resource, as: nil)
    method_name = "#{as || resource.to_s}_path" 
    define_method(method_name) do
      "/#{resource}"
    end
  end
end

class Routes
  extend Routable

  get :products
  get :users, as: :customers
end


routes = Routes.new
routes.respond_to?(:users_path) # => false
routes.respond_to?(:customers_path) # => true
routes.respond_to?(:products_path) # => true
routes.customers_path # => "/users"
```

As for the "where it is *actually* happening", you're welcome to peruse rails' code, now that you know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in rails, your routes will be mapped to a controller method.

What you are doing is setting the route as a GET, accessible through the endpoint `/articles`.

You are setting this to map to a method defined in controller `A`, the method signature being `B`.  The `as` keyword is simply naming the route.

E.g., in your `config/routes.rb` you may have

`get "/articles" => "arts#articles", as: "arts"`

Which would direct the `/articles` GET request to, a method `articles` defined in the controller:

`/app/controllers/arts_controller.rb`

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> Then by simply including the code
>
> `as: "arts"`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Prefix      Verb    URI Pattern                  Controller#Action  Named Helper

articles     GET    /articles(.:format)           articles#index   articles_path or articles_url
```

The prefix like **articles** is a  path helpers and so the named helper is articles_path or articles_url .

The bottom line is when you call helpers like link_to or form_tag etc - they will require paths to populate different actions in your app's routing structure.

As Rails favours convention over configuration & DRY programming, meaning if you can reference these path helpers over using standard urls, it will allow you to make one reference & chance the route as required

eg:

Calling articles_path is far more powerful than referencing /articles every time

The prefix let's you use shortcuts such as articles_path or articles_url in your controllers and views. These come in very handy when doing things like redirecting users to a specific page or generating dynamic links.

To customize the path helper, you can change the reference in the routes file, like this:

```
 GET '/articles', to: 'articles#index', as: 'all_articles'
```

This would change the prefix to **all_articles_path** instead of articles_path

This allows you to define custom routes / path helpers, allowing you to call those as you wish

Answer (score 0):

The routes are created in the Rails library code in the `ActionDispatch` module.

You can read the code in the GutHub repository in the methods [add](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/63f0c04850dd0bcdc7d35266e81fa1a7778570a8/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L106) and [add route](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/63f0c04850dd0bcdc7d35266e81fa1a7778570a8/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L570).